CC BY-SA 2.5 License marked as denied license in the FOSSA tool after upgrading to React Native 0.74 version
We have an existing React Native project that was upgraded from 0.71.0 to 0.74.0 latest version.
We are us a tool FOSSA to scan the license-related issues in the NPM libraries used in the project.
We found a license issue in the React Native 0.74 framework. At this point, we are failing to follow the industry's compliance because of the issue with the license. Adding the FOSSA issue screenshot below.
Questions:

Is the issue found in the license(CC BY SA 2.5) it valid issue?
Can we use a license (CC BY SA 2.5) in the enterprise application?
Is the license CC BY-SA 2.5 available as an open source?

FOSSA Dashboard screenshot -


As far as I can see, there is no issue here; your employer has made the decision to not allow you to use CC-BY-SA (2.5). You need to ask this question internally.

I am not sure that we currently have enough information to answer. The issue seems to be rooted in your 'licensing policy'. You might need to ask the person who created this policy for a comment. Can you pls post that comment here?

@Martin_in_AUT Thanks for the reply. I will check with the team.

It looks like a false detection of the tool. If you look at the top-level LICENSE page of MDN (https://github.com/mdn/content/blob/main/LICENSE.md), the first part of the text mentions that what MDN publishes is "under various open source licenses", and specifically that "prose content" is under the CC-BY-SA license but that "code examples and snippets" are under CC0 or MIT, depending on publishing date. I would guess that since CC-BY-SA is the one first mentioned in the LICENSE.md, then the tool assumes that that license applies to everything you extract, including the code comments.

It looks like the fault is in whoever extracted comments and put them into this file and others like it. In the source itself I see that message, so I'm guessing someone used some tool for convenience at some point and just left it there without giving much thought to it: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/main/packages/react-native/src/private/webapis/dom/geometry
You could issue a bug against React Native and say that the "DOMRect" API documentation and so on written by MDN are not in fact CC-BY-SA licensed, but CC0/MIT licensed; I'm not sure if they'll want to fix it, though.

@Brandin Thank you for the indication!

@Brandin An Issue is raised and got the answer from the React Native dev team - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/46594.

@MehulPatel I suppose it could be a matter of interpretation, whether those API documentation snippets count as "prose" or as "code snippets and examples". I suppose, by a very literalist interpretation, then they are not "code snippets" since they don't appear formatted as such in the source .md files.

The license scanning tool correctly identified that there is a file within React Native that has content under the CC BY-SA 2.5 license.
For reasons only known to the policy makers of your company, the CC BY-SA 2.5 license is not considered acceptable. An educated guess would be that the copyleft/share-alike clause of the license plays a role in that decision.
In this particular case and depending on how your project depends on React Native, this finding by the FOSSA tool could be classified as a false-positive. The comment block that triggers the failure states that it only applies to the JSDoc blocks. Cut away in this screenshot is another comment block stating that (the rest of) the file is under the MIT license.
If you don't do anything with those JSDoc blocks (you don't publish generated documentation, you don't have copies of them, etc.), then the CC BY-SA 2.5 license on them does not affect you and you can argue that the flag by FOSSA is a false-positive. If it then flags again on a different file, you have to perform a similar analysis to see if that is again a false-positive.
